# How to check the linearity of a function?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I check a function is linear or not? I've searched about it and got the following formula: $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$.

How can I use the above formula to determine whether these functions are linear?
$f(x) = x+4$

$f(x) = 5$

and can anyone tell me what are "affine functions"? My teacher told me that$ f(x) = x+4$ is not linear, it is an affine function which is close to linear but is not linear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $f(x)=x+4$ is not "a fine function", but an *affine* function.

Comment: You mean an [affine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) function, not "a fine" function.

Comment: Say that your function is $f(x)=x+4$ and now write it with $y$ instead to get $f(y)=y+4$. If you now say I want give the function the parameter $x+y$, then you get $f(x+y)=x+y+4$, while $f(x)+f(y)=x+y+8$.

Comment: I don't get the hate here. I think $f(x) = x+4$ is a perfectly fine function.

Answer (score 4):

For $f(x) = x + 4$ we have: $f(a+b) = a + b + 4 \neq f(a) + f(b) = a + b + 8$

Similarly for $g(x) = 5$, $g(a+b) = 5 \neq g(a) + g(b) = 5 + 5 = 10$

Answer (score 1):

You know that a linear function satisfies the following property: $$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$$ and you want to determine whether a particular function $g$ is linear, so you just check whether this property holds. For example, we define the function $g$ as $x\mapsto 6x+1$, thus:
\begin{align*}
g(a+b)
= 6(a+b)+1
&= 6a+6b+1 \\
&\boldsymbol{\neq} 6a + 6b+2=6a+1+6b+1=g(a)+g(b).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $g$ is not a linear function.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the properties for linear functions on wikipedia.

for f(x) = x+4, do:

f(ax) = ax + 4 != a*f(x) = ax+4a

which violates the property of linear function, so it is not a linear.

for f(x) = 5, it is similar.

I'm not sure about what is a fine function.